# trying to fix a crontab file duplicate by PID table

Tags: php

I'm trying to develop a crontab task that every 5 seconds check my email. Normally I could request it every 1 minute instead of 5 seconds, but reading some other posts with no solution, I found one with the same problem than me. The script, after a period of time, was stopping. This is not a real problem cause I can configure a crontab task and make `sleep(5)` Also I have the same 1and1 server as the other question, which I'm including here.

[PHP script stops running arbitrarily with no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084067/php-script-stops-running-arbitrarily-with-no-errors)

The real problem I had when I tried to solve this via crontab, every minute a new PID was created, so in an hour I could get almost 50 process at the same time doing the same.

Here I include the .php file called by crontab every minute:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
require_once ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder1/path.php' );
require_once ( CLASSES . 'Builder.php');            
$UIModules = Builder::getUIModules();
$UIModules->getfile();
```

So I found a solution by checking the PID table. The idea is if in the PID table are running 2 process, then that means the last proccess is still working, so just finish doing anything. If in the PID table there's just 1 process running, that means the latest process that was working has expired so we can use this new one. The way is something like I show on the next code:

```
$var_aux = exec("ps -A | grep php");
if (!isarray($var_aux)){
   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
   require_once ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder1/path.php' );
   require_once ( CLASSES . 'Builder.php');         
   $UIModules = Builder::getUIModules();
   $UIModules->getfile();
}
```

I'm not sure about the condition `isarray($var_aux)` cause $var_aux always returns me the last PID process, so it returns a string of 28 characters, but in this case we want to return more than a process so the condition could even change to `if (strlen($var) < 34)`. Note: I've given more margin to the len, cause sometime process take longer than 9999, so it's 1 lenght more.

The main problem I found on this is the exec sentence just print me the last process, in other words, it always returns me a string with a lenght of 28 (The PID for that script).

I don't know if what I've purposed is a crazy idea, but is it possible to get all the PID table with php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a much simpler solution than emulating crontab in php: use contab
make multiple entries to check every 5 seconds an then call your php program.

A good description of how to set up crontab to perform subminute action can be found here:

https://usu.li/how-to-run-a-cron-job-every-x-seconds

This solution only requires the maximum of 12 processes running every minute.